# Converting text to date format SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I am using SSIS to import data from Excel to SQL Server database.

The date column has `nvarchar` data type, and I want to change it to a date data type `YYYY-MM-DD`.

If the value is null then I want to get null.

I used `[mycolumn]` date,  on the create a new table option on the OLE DB destination.

Is that right?

Comment: Shouting doesn't help. It makes the question harder *and* annoys people. Dates have no format anyway, they are binary values. You need to convert the text to a date with a [Data Conversion transform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/convert-data-type-by-using-data-conversion-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15) or parse it and return a date with a [Derived Column Transform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derive-column-values-by-using-the-derived-column-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: What's the *actual* problem anyway? Did SSIS complain that it can't insert `nvarchar` into a `date` column? What is the format of the string data? If it's `YYYY-MM-DD` you may need nothing more than a Data Conversion, or even a `cast(someField as date)` in the *source* query. `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYYMMDD` are recognized as valid `date` or `datetime2` literals no matter what the culture or collation. With `datetime`, only `YYYYMMDD` is unambiguous for historical reasons

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a Data Conversion Data Flow Component.
2. Right click, Show Advanced Editor...
3. Goto Input and Output Properties
4. Expand Data Conversion Output and click on the date column
5. Set FastParse to True in the Custom Properties
6. Make sure the data type is set to database date [DT_DBDATE]
7. Run the ssis package again the yyyymmdd dates should flow smoothly from nvarchar to date

Answer (score -1):

Convert [mycolumn] to the needed DATE format before inserting it to the table. Try this:-

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), [mycolumn],126)
```

Comment: SQL Server recognizes `YYYY-MM-DD` as a `date` literal directly. If the text makes it to the server in that form, it would need no conversion to insert into a `date` column